# Left right button for slider like Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Want to slide my images right and left on click. I use jquery for that. but problem is that when I continue to click on right the div goes right and blank space display. I tried but it not fixes. I'm a newbie in jquery.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html class=''>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style class="cp-pen-styles">
.row_outer {
  *overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.row__inner {
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 70.3125px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.tile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 326px;
  height: 192px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
          transform-origin: center left;
}
.tile__img {
  width: 326px;
  height: 192px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
.tile__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 450ms opacity;
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}
.tile__details:after,
.tile__details:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: #000;
}
.tile__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
.tile__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
}
.tile:hover .tile__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.row__inner:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-72.5px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-72.5px, 0, 0);
}
.row__inner:hover .tile {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile:hover ~ .tile {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(215px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(215px, 0, 0);
}

    .buttons{
        position: absolute;        
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: -190px;
    }

    .buttons button{        
        height: 100%;
        padding: 7px 20px;
        color: #fa8f33;
        border: 1px solid
    }

    .left{
    float: left;    
    }

    .right{
        float: right;
    }

/* Sweep To Right */
.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fa8f33;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* Sweep To Left */
.hvr-sweep-to-left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fa8f33;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-left:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-left:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}    

</style></head><body>
<div class="contain">


  <div class="row_outer">
    <div class="row__inner">


      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img " src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img " src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-3.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-4.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-5.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-6.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-7.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-8.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-9.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-10.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-11.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-12.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-13.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-14.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-15.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-16.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-17.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-18.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-19.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
         <button class="left hvr-sweep-to-left " id="left"><span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span></button>
         <button href="" class="right hvr-sweep-to-right " id="right"><span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span></button>
     </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $( "#right" ).click(function() {
      $( ".tile" ).animate({ "left": "+=365px" }, "1000" );
    });

    $( "#left" ).click(function(){
      $( ".tile" ).animate({ "left": "-=365px" }, "1000" );
    });
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: According to your linked stylesheets, you're using Bootstrap. Why don't you simplify and use [Bootstrap's carousel](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php)?

Comment: Ok you gave a code, but where are your buttons ? Have you try something ?

Comment: i edit my code. plz look once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this out [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mz5hrqgL/2/)

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
var length = $(".tile").length;

$( "#right" ).click(function() {
    if(slideIndex != 1){
  $( ".tile" ).animate({ "left": "+=365px" }, "1000" );
  slideIndex--;
  }      
});

$( "#left" ).click(function() {
    if(slideIndex >= length-1 ){

  }else{
  $( ".tile" ).animate({ "left": "-=365px" }, "1000" );
  slideIndex++;
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank this works. just i put == instead of != in if condition.

Comment: But problem is i want to stop when I reached at last div it stop move

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Every one who looked into it. I Fix my problem.

This is my Solution :

```
var $par = $('.row_outer').scrollLeft(546) ; 
$('.right, .left').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();                     
    var n = $(this).hasClass("left") ? "+=182" : "-=182";
    $par.animate({scrollLeft: n});
});
```